# Trying to update visibility of buttons in a list view android

Tags: android, listview, android-mediaplayer, audio-recording, android-mediarecorder

I've been working on this chat application in android for quiet a few months, using firebase like most people do. Recently I've been working on adding voice recordings and I have no issues in that. The problem arises when I try to inflate the list view with a layout for the media player to play/pause and show progress of the recorded audio. The layout has two buttons, Play and Pause with interchanging visibilities when I click on them. The problem arises when I click on the buttons, the button visibility of different recorded list view items are updated instead of changing the corresponding list view item. I don't think my adapter implements view holder pattern but I've seen similar projects work just fine without it. I'am quiet clueless as to what might be the problem. Also, to make the list view button clickable, I've added the following line (android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants") in the inflated layout's xml which worked fine in another project I did.
My adapter code for the recorded audio's list view:

```
 else if(map.get("TYPE").toString().contains("RECORDING")){
        if (map.get("FROM").toString().contains(mAuth.getUid())) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recording_user_list, null);
        }
        else {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_image_layout_other, null);
        }

        TextView mTime = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_recording_received_time);
        mTime.setText(time);
        finalRecorderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                "/" + map.get("MESSAGE").toString();

        playButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_recording_play);
        pauseButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_recording_pause);
        pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        if(mediaPlayer != null){
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(map.get("MESSAGE").toString());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                pauseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                      mediaPlayer.start();
                if(recordingFlag){
                            mediaPlayer.seekTo(audioPosition);
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Hey", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        });

        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                audioPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                recordingFlag = true;
            }
        });



        Log.e(TAG, "setRecording: Path " + finalRecorderPath );

        Log.e(TAG, "onClick: Playing");
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                audioPosition = 0;
                recordingFlag = false;
                mediaPlayer.release();
                Log.e(TAG, "onCompletion: Completed playing audio");
            }
        });

    }
```

My inflated xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@drawable/text_box_sender"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:focusable="false"
            android:id="@+id/list_view_recording_play"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@color/colorTransparent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_play_arrow_24"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:focusable="false"
            android:id="@+id/list_view_recording_pause"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@color/colorTransparent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_pause_24"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/list_recording_progress_bar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/list_view_recording_play"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_below="@id/list_view_recording_pause"
            android:id="@+id/list_recording_received_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My list view adapters complete code is attached below:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.chatbox.R;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.UUID;

public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String TAG = "Chat Adapter";
    FirebaseStorage storage;
    private ArrayList<HashMap> chatList;
    StorageReference mDataRef;
    private Activity activity;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private String finalRecorderPath;
    private ImageButton playButton, pauseButton;
    int audioPosition;
    private boolean recordingFlag = false;

    public ChatAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap> chatList){
        this.chatList = chatList;
        this.activity = activity;

        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        mDataRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://chat-box-v2.appspot.com");
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return chatList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return chatList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final HashMap map = chatList.get(position);


        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        String time = map.get("TIME").toString();
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = format.parse(time);
            Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

            format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String chatDate = format.format(date);
            String curDate = format.format(currentTime);

            if (chatDate.contains(curDate)) {
                format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
                time = format.format(date);
                Log.e(TAG, "Adapter Time Matches");
            } else {
                format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm aa");
                time = format.format(date);
                Log.e(TAG, "Time doesnt Match");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Chat Adapter Time Exception: " + e.toString());
        }

        if(map.get("TYPE").toString().contains("MESSAGE")) {

            if (map.get("FROM").toString().contains(mAuth.getUid()))
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sender, null);

            else
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reciever, null);

            TextView mName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_name_list);
            TextView mMessage = convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_text_list);
            TextView mTime = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_time_list);


            /***Date And Time Formatter For List View Chat**/

            try {
                mName.setText(map.get("NAME").toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "getView:  Name" + e.toString());
            }

            try {
                mMessage.setText(map.get("MESSAGE").toString());
                mTime.setText(time);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }

        else if(map.get("TYPE").toString().contains("IMAGE")){

            if (map.get("FROM").toString().contains(mAuth.getUid()))
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_image_layout_user, null);

            else
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_image_layout_other, null);

            ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_image_view);
            ProgressBar progressBar = convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress_circular_bar_image);
            GetImageBitmap(map.get("MESSAGE").toString(), imageView, progressBar);
        }

        else if(map.get("TYPE").toString().contains("RECORDING")){
            if (map.get("FROM").toString().contains(mAuth.getUid())) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recording_user_list, null);
            }
            else {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_image_layout_other, null);
            }

            TextView mTime = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_recording_received_time);
            mTime.setText(time);
            finalRecorderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                    "/" + map.get("MESSAGE").toString();

            playButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_recording_play);
            pauseButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_recording_pause);
            pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            if(mediaPlayer != null){
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(map.get("MESSAGE").toString());
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    playButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    pauseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                          mediaPlayer.start();
                    if(recordingFlag){
                                mediaPlayer.seekTo(audioPosition);
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Hey", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            });

            pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    audioPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                    recordingFlag = true;
                }
            });



            Log.e(TAG, "setRecording: Path " + finalRecorderPath );

            Log.e(TAG, "onClick: Playing");
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    audioPosition = 0;
                    recordingFlag = false;
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    Log.e(TAG, "onCompletion: Completed playing audio");
                }
            });

        }
        return convertView;
    }

    void GetImageBitmap(final String url, final ImageView imageView, final ProgressBar progressBar){
        Log.e(TAG, "GetImageBitmap: " + url );
        final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                FileInputStream fileInputStream;
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                try {
                    fileInputStream = activity.openFileInput(url);
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream);
                    final Bitmap finalBitmap = bitmap;
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(finalBitmap);
                                imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                                imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    
                    Log.e(TAG, "GetImageBitmap: Bitmap");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    final StorageReference ref = storage.getReference().child("images/message/" + url);
                    ref.getBytes(1020*1024*7).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                            Log.e("TestData", "onSuccess: " + "successfully downloaded image" );
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                            try {
                                Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
                                imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                                imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            saveImage(activity, bitmap, url);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

    }

    void saveImage(Context context, Bitmap bitmap, String name){
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong or I'm missing out on? I'm still quiet new to this :/ I will be grateful to anyone who helps me sort out what's wrong with my code. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, apparently the reason behind this was not implementing view holder pattern. I did it and it works like a charm :)
Note to people from the future:
-Never ever use list view, recycler-view is more advanced and reliable.
-Always implement view holder pattern.